# Smooth movement, and possibly move JS to CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a small working piece.

HTML:

```
<div id="it">X</div>
```

CSS:

```
#it {
    background: blue;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#it').animate({
    left: '+=100',
    top: '+=100'
}, 400, function() {
        $(this).animate({
        top: '-=100'
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '-=100',
            top: '+=100'
        }, 400, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                top: '-=100'
            }, 400);
        });
    });
});
```

Everything aforementioned put together in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn7UE/)

What I need help with:

1. Loop the JS. Besides, I'm almost sure that something can be done to simplify that repeated nested code.
2. Make the movement smooth. I.e., make the object fly in a single curved line tracing a "tilted 8" shape, rather than in 4 strait lines.
3. If possible, get rid of JS and replace it with CSS3.

Also not necessarily required for my project, but would be amazing if there was a way to rotate the object along the way so it always faces the direction it is heading. Like as if you were watching a race car from above.

Comment: Geo please read my comment on my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have already converted your JavaScript to CSS3: [here it is for you](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/amJ2e/54/).

It is looped and uses CSS3, and works in IE 10, chrome, firefox, and safari. I don't have opera so I cannot test and IE 9 and down will need to use a CSS3 shiv.

```
@-webkit-keyframes move {
0%   {top:  100px;
      left: 100px;}
25%  {top:  250px;
      left: 250px;}
50%  {top:  100px;
      left: 250px;}
75%  {top:  250px;
      left: 100px;}
100% {top:  100px;
      left: 100px;}
}
```

That code replaces the JavaScript you had; it creates the animation in segments. It is only  the webkit part of the animation syntax though, to make sure you cover all of your bases, don't forget `@-moz-` and `@keyframes` for the standard spec animation syntax.

```
-webkit-animation:move 5s infinite;
```

This CSS3 rule tells the parser what element should be using the declared animation.

Rotating the item can be done using the transform css declaration, which I will work on and update ASAP.​ So far I have gotten transforms to work in every browser. Additionally, I tilted the whole animation at an angle just like you asked so that it will look like an infinity sign. Getting a smooth corner turn is quite difficult right now without complex math or advanced use of transitions and extra animations, I am not quite sure how to do it right. I will see what can be done.

Comment: I have updated my jsfiddle to work on mozilla, IE 10, chrome, and safari

Comment: are the rotations what you wanted or differently? The smoothness cannot be done at this time by the way. I will see how it can be done in a different way though.

Comment: The loop is fine, i like the ease too. I don't see the rotation. And yes, I'm afraid the smoothness might require JS back again (and some difficult `sin()` or `cos()` math functions). Thank you though.

Comment: take a look on chrome, i am adding in other browser support.

Comment: Ok geo, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/amJ2e/7/ I linked it in the answer and updated that link because it was on update 6 before, but until stackoverflow allows everyone to see it you can just view it from this link I gave you above.

Comment: wow, cool!! It's almost 100% complete now. #1 (loop), 3 (no JS), and even extra point (rotation) are done. The only one left is #2. The object should go at a constant speed, no cornering, tracing a tilted 8 shape (like an infinity sign ∞)

Comment: Yea I know, any curved paths right now need to be animated using JavaScript or jQuery, both of which are not an option for you, so I won't add them in. I commented out the container's tilt and you can change it to whatever angle you'd like.

Comment: right, that's what I figured too. Okay, @Ilan thank you for such a great work!

Comment: @Geo I added a little content to the jsfiddle to show you a constant speed animation vs. an eased animation.

Answer (score 1):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/Tn7UE/1/
i have added `transform:rotate();` to change direction. and `setInterval` for loop.

Comment: this is useful for js, but the set interval can be done in css easily

Comment: definitely +1 for the rotation! The only thing left is to smooth it so it curves the corners.

Comment: also, great idea with the arrow - so you can see the current direction!

Comment: agreed. the rotation was very easy once i slowed down the timer though.